# How do I correctly include golang protobuf/ptypes for protoc when using dep?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc, twirp

I'm having trouble including the [google/protobuf/timestamp.proto](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#well-known-types) well known type, when using [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep).

I get an error: `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found`

service.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

package com.rynop.platform;
option go_package = "rpc";

service PlatformService {
  rpc Test(EmptyMessage) returns (EmptyMessage);
}

message EmptyMessage { }

message A {  
    string summary = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp start = 2;
}

message B {
  repeated A foos = 1;
}
```

Install package containing timestamp .proto def:

```
dep ensure -add github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp
```

Run `protoc` and get error:

```
build/bin/protoc -Ivendor -I. --twirp_typescript_out=version=v6:./clients/ts-json/ rpc/service.proto
google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.
```

The dir containing timestamp's .proto definition exists:

```
file vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.proto
vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.proto: ASCII text
```

I'm installing protoc locally because I wan't to lock-in/tie a protoc version to this project:

```
# fetch the protoc compiler
OS_NAME=$(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(OS_NAME),Darwin)
    PROTOC_URL=https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.1/protoc-3.7.1-osx-x86_64.zip
endif
ifeq ($(OS_NAME),Linux)
    PROTOC_URL=https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.1/protoc-3.7.1-linux-x86_64.zip
endif
build/protoc build/bin/protoc:
    mkdir -p build/protoc/bin build/bin
    cd build/protoc && curl -L -o protoc.zip $(PROTOC_URL) && \
        unzip protoc.zip && mv bin/protoc ../bin/protoc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `protoc` error you are getting relates to your `INCLUDE` path.

When you installed the `protoc` compiler (e.g. to `/usr/local/bin/protoc`), for it to pick up google's standard proto definitions like `timestamp.proto` - these need to be added somewhere along your `INCLUDE` path (on MacOS/Linux one may use `/usr/local/include`). Note: the protoc headers should have been included with the protoc compiler.

So your proto import file would typically be located here:

```
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
```

This path will be referenced when the `protoc` compiler sees an import like:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
```

So check your `INCLUDE` path and ensure the `protoc` headers are installed correctly.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  It works if I do `-I/usr/local/include -I.` . However I'm using dep to "lock in" my dependencies.  I want to do the same thing with protoc.  I don't want a global install of protoc because I wan't to lock-in/tie a protoc version to this project. I've updated my post with how I install. Is there a best practice for this that still gets the headers? Or am I being overly concerned here (making something out of nothing)?

Comment: I agree/share your concerns about the lock-in. You will encounter `proto2` and `proto3` projects and being able to juggle them on a build system is key.  In my makefiles, I explicitly have `PROTOC2` or `PROTOC3` env vars pointing to the relevant compiler path - and similarly use the `-IPATH` flag to point to associated standard headers. I'll update this answer shortly to include those details...

Comment: Thanks. My zip included the `include` dir and I never realized it.  I changed to `-Ibuild/protoc/include -I.` and now I'm golden.  THANK YOU!