# Generating Python and Go code from the same .proto file - problem with imports

Tags: python, go, grpc, proto

I'm having hard time generating the code for Python and Go using shared .proto file. The problematic part is that I am utilising the `timestamp.proto` (by google) which needs to be imported differently depending on what language the generated code should be in.

The Python code generator requires this form:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
```

While Go code generator requires this:

```
import "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.proto";
```

Is it possible to make this import work for both languages? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proto path is wrong:

```
import "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.proto"; // WRONG path
```

This is the correct import path no matter what language you are using - Go or Python etc:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"; // correct path for any language (go, python etc)
```

---

This `timestamp.proto` file is located by the `protoc-gen-go` tool (when generating Go code) using its default `INCLUDE_PATH`.

For example, on my Mac for instance, the default `INCLUDE_PATH` is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.7.1/include
```

with the full proto file path being:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.7.1/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
```

You can see other standard proto definitions that come with your gRPC installation like `duration.proto`:

```
$ pwd # my default gRPC include path
/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.7.1/include

$ find . -name "*.proto"

./google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
./google/protobuf/field_mask.proto
./google/protobuf/api.proto
./google/protobuf/duration.proto
./google/protobuf/struct.proto
./google/protobuf/wrappers.proto
./google/protobuf/source_context.proto
./google/protobuf/any.proto
./google/protobuf/type.proto
./google/protobuf/empty.proto
./google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.proto
./google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
```

Provided you have installed the gRPC toolkit (and its headers) in the correct location, as per the [install docs](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases), then the above directory hierarchy should match for any OS build.

P.S. this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554322/1218512) explains how to set an explicit `INCLUDE_PATH` when using the proto-compiler.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it today. Can you tell me, however, why the path that you say is wrong works?

Comment: You can import any `.proto` file from any location using any relative path. As long as the compiler can match the `INCLUDE` path with the relative import path to a real file it will work. So clearly on one of your OSes the file path `github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.proto` exists somewhere where the protoc compiler's `INCLUDE` path.

Comment: The reason I said your `github.ibm.com/...` path is "wrong", is because `timestamp.proto` is such a standard definition, it really should be imported from your gRPC toolkit install. This ensure you are using consistent definitions e.g. if you are using syntax `proto3` you want to make sure you have standard imports that also use `proto3` etc.